# Filter dataframe by date in datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Good morning everybody,

I am currently writing a bot that is supposed to populate a browser based system with data.
Therefore the macro pulls data from excel into a dataframe and has to decide first what data needs to be put into this system. In this check all dates of one column in the dataframe are checked against the current date.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw8ar.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQUFG.png)

Both the current date ("datetimeObj") and the column ("Approved until incl.") are formatted in datetime (as per my understanding).
**The problem** is that this check is not working with this message:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w0Yj.png)

I tried the check with only one item from the column and then it is working:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRkrm.png)

I hope some of you can help me here.
Thanks in advance,

All the best!
Melonenbauer

Comment: Could you try to print the type of the column values and confirm if they are all in datetime format and not string?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and congratulations on your first post! There are a couple of rules to follow. _Do not post images of code or error messages or dataframes_. Post the code instead. Please read more here: [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples), [mcve],  [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: okay sure thanks for the hint!

Comment: I did it shows me that the column is in the dtype object.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you should have strings in the xlsx_import["Approved until incl."]

Try to following to see what's going on...

Import libraries:

`from datetime import datetime`

`import pandas as pd`

Then create a sample dict full of dates:

`date_dict = dict({'time':[datetime(2020,1,1,12,10,10),datetime(2020,1,2,12,10,10)]})`

Then create a pandas data frame. This one has dates on the column values

`df = pd.DataFrame(date_dict)`

Then we generate a sample date for testing:

`date = datetime(2020,1,1,17,10,10)`

Then the final test:

`is_older = df['time'] < date`

when displaying like this: `print(is_older)` You will get no error, the 1st item True, 2nd False

Then we do the same but this time with a data frame with strings in the columns instead of date times:

We generate a new sample dict:

`date_dict = dict({'time':["2020-1-1 12:10:10","2020-1-2 12:10:10"]})`

Then we create a new dataframe filled with strings:

`df_str = pd.DataFrame(date_dict)`

And we finally test it:

`is_older2 = df_str['time'] < date`

The error you show appears.

Comment: Hey thanks! This helped me out to solve the problem. The problem was that there was one item which was a string inside of the column "Approved until incl.".

Comment: I'm glad it helped! ;)

Comment: You can check the type of your df columns with the df.info() and check if they are strings (object) or datetime. Enjoy coding!